# PHP registration not inserting new user into table

Tags: php, mysql, database, registration

I'm following a tutorial and I've run into an issue where I can complete my registration form but my info isn't saved into the database table. All my code is the same as the tutorial. Am I missing something?

Obviously it has to do with my $insert variable, but I can't figure out what it is.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name']);      
        $user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_pass']);
        $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_email']);
        $user_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_country']);
        $user_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_number']);
        $user_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_address']);
        $user_gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_gender']);
        $user_b_day = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b_day']);

        $user_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $user_tmp = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];

        if($user_address=='' OR $user_country=="" OR $user_image=="" OR $user_gender=='') {
            echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields.')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Your email is not valid.')</script>";
            exit();
        }
        $sel_email = "SELECT * FROM register_user WHERE user_email='" . $user_email . "';";
        $run_email = mysqli_query($con, $sel_email);        

        $check_email = mysqli_num_rows($run_email);

        if($check_email==1) {
            echo "<script>alert('This email is already registered. Please choose another.')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;

            move_uploaded_file($user_tmp, "images/$user_image");

            $insert = "INSERT INTO register_user (user_name, 
                                                user_pass, 
                                                user_email, 
                                                user_country, 
                                                user_number, 
                                                user_address, 
                                                user_gender, 
                                                user_b_day, 
                                                user_image, 
                                                register_date) 
                        VALUES ('$user_name', 
                                '$user_pass', 
                                '$user_email', 
                                '$user_country', 
                                '$user_number', 
                                '$user_address', 
                                '$user_gender', 
                                '$user_b_day', 
                                '$user_image', 
                                 NOW())";

            mysqli_query($con, $insert);

            echo "<script>alert('Registration successful.')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('home.php', '_self' )</script>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you try to debug this? Does your code get beyond `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: echoing above, what errors if any your getting and is your connection working etc also try debugging each section so to find the actual section that might be the cause

Comment: I'm not getting any errors; I get sent to the `home.php` page. The image appears in my /image/ folder, but my actual registration information is not saved inside the `register_user` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no error message, try this:

```
   $insert = "INSERT INTO register_user (user_name, 
                                                user_pass, 
                                                user_email, 
                                                user_country, 
                                                user_number, 
                                                user_address, 
                                                user_gender, 
                                                user_b_day, 
                                                user_image, 
                                                register_date) 
                        VALUES ('".$user_name."', 
                                '".$user_pass."', 
                                '".$user_email."', 
                                '".$user_country."', 
                                '".$user_number."', 
                                '".$user_address."', 
                                '".$user_gender."', 
                                '".$user_b_day."', 
                                '".$user_image."', 
                                 NOW())";
```

Comment: Still no. Maybe I messed up when I created my table? Is there something I can check on phpmyadmin maybe?

Comment: Go to your phpmyadmin->your database->sql. Copy and paste this code, but paste some values instead variables.

Comment: Shamil- thank you, this helped solve it; the birthday name under `structure` in my table was different than what's in my code, so I updated it. Thanks again.

Comment: @vytfla It seems you forgot to vote for answer as helpful :)

Comment: Correct! Sorry about that.